# sp_send_dbmail fails when mailing queries, but no error returned, query just hangs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-mail

I have an issue SQL Server 2005.

`sp_send_dbmail` fails when mailing out with the result of a query (inline or attatchment).

No error message is given / reported, the query just keeps executing but nothing returned (have left it for 28 minutes so far) with no time out etc.

Mails go out fine when no queries are involved.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you run the query on its own? Does it run okay?

Comment: @Jon - Hi Jon, yes query works fine... any query with mail causes issue, even Select 1;

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the T-SQL you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you're running on a deadlock situation? Create a test table that you know for sure no one is accessing it, populate it with some sample data, and run a query in proc against that table just to test it out.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, we have done just that with a query we know has no issue etc, but the same occurs when the query is part of the sp_send_dbmail

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Execute your send_mail T-SQL statement as yourself, and try also executing the same T-SQL statement as the SQL Server Agent account. If it goes through as the agent and not your own account, it's a relay issue.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Agent is the sender if you are indicating jobs are sending successfully. When running a query manually, you are the sender.

You can test by logging into your SSMS query window as the Agent Account.

I'd suggest talking with your mail admin to see if you have rights under your account to [relay mail](http://www.more2know.nl/2010/11/03/exchange-2010-relay-permissions/).

Answer (score -1):

I've come across recently myself. The problem, in my case, seemed to be with the number of records returned by the query.

To troubleshoot, try limiting the results by using `SELECT TOP`

Comment: In comments Jonno said the issue persisted even with a 'SELECT 1', so no. of records returned isn't the problem.